# How to get all the emojis in a server and make the bot send the emojis in the chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the bot to send all the emojis in a server in the chat, as emojis.

```
if (message.content === "listemojis") {
   const emojiList = message.guild.emojis.map((e, x) => (x + ' = ' + e) + ' | ' +e.name).join('\n');
   message.channel.send(emojiList);
}
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work. Any other way?

Comment: try to edit it to `message.guild.emojis.cache.map`

Comment: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body. I think that is because of a long message. How do i fix that?

Comment: i looks there is a limit of message you couldnt send all of the emojis as a message

Comment: Okay. So, how do i a make it send 2 messages or 3 messages in that case?

Comment: do you mean split all of the emojis into 2 or 3 messages?

Comment: yeah. Thats what i mean

Comment: first check what is the length of the emojis array then divide it to 3 or any small number after that run a counter that increases by one if it get the limit send the message and send a new one

Comment: Okay I guess...

Comment: or you could use `slice` to split it for you

Comment: You could also just iteratively add the emojis to a string (and send a message before it crosses 2000 characters) to maximize the message, since around ~65 emojis should snugly fit inside of one message (assuming short emoji names).

Comment: here is a simple way to split all of the array just specify the length of each chunk [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks#8495740)

Comment: Actually, `TextChannel.send()` has a built in option for this. `message.channel.send(emojList, { split: true })`